# Eclipse: How to show user who changed this line in CVS?

Tags: eclipse, cvs, history, visualization

Someone once showed me a cool IntelliJ Idea plugin that would show all the user commit information from CVS right there in the Java source editor.

It had a vertical bar on the right of the window and every code block changed/committed by a user was highlighted with different color and mouse-over would show the details about user and version etc.

I am craving for something similar in Eclipse.

Any pointers?

Comment: FYI this is done on the cvs command line with 'cvs annotate filename'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you looking for [this](http://stuvel.eu/archive/42/blame-support-in-eclipse)?

> Right-click on a file, choose "Team", "Show annotation" and you'll see who last edited which line of code.

Here is an illustration from the "[What's New in Eclipse 3.2](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/06/28/whats-new-in-eclipse-3-2-java-development-tools.html?page=3)" article from [onjava.com](http://www.onjava.com/), which adds:

> Hovering over a change block will show the developer name, date, and comments that were entered for that change. It will also highlight other sections of code in the rest of the file that were contributed in the same revision.

[image: CVS Quick Diff annotations show color-based annotations of who did what in the file.]
<sub>(source: [onjava.com](http://www.onjava.com/onjava/2006/06/28/graphics/fig03.gif))</sub>

Comment: +1 and sorry to be late for the illustration (remember http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722003/system-getpropertyuser-dir-anomaly-in-eclipse/722025#722025 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707194/tool-to-remove-unnecessary-dependencies-in-a-java-project/707206#707206 ?)

Comment: VonC strikes again! Nice link and nice picture, as usual.